# How to correctly patch Java class in a JAR file?

Tags: java, file, path, jar, classpath

I need to patch a class that is in a JA file, in a package following the form pack1.pack2.pack3.com. So the full name of class is:

```
pack1.pack2.pack3.com.classtopatch
```

I have a folder in my application:

```
c:/app/patches
```

Should I simply copy the class to c:/app/patches/classtopath.class file or do I 
need to create the entire folder tree like:

```
c:/app/patches/pack1/pack2/pack3/com
```

and in pack1/pack2/pack3/com put classtopath.clas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to create the directory structure to match your package name.

Create `c:/app/patches/pack1/pack2/pack3/com` and put `classtopath.class` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear, but if you've got class files on the file system, then they should be in the appropriate package structure.

If you're packing it into a jar file then the jar file itself can be anywhere, but the package structure should be present *in* the jar file.

Comment: The classloader look for files on classpath. In docs written that classpath for .class files finished with /. So my question - need copy to substiture only 1 file .class or create all tree of folders that corresponds package name.

Comment: @user710818: You need to copy the tree - you've got to preserve the package structure. It's unclear what your question has to do with jar files though...

Comment: I need substitute 1 class in jar.

Comment: @user710818 - we know that!  Please pay attention to what Jon is saying.  What is unclear from your question is the *fully qualified class name* of the class that you are replacing.  It is *that name* that determines where you must put the replacement class in the JAR file.

Comment: @user710818: So why not edit the contents of the jar file itself, rather than putting a single extra class on the classpath?